# Why doesn't request.rawurl include the http://localhost part?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

When I call Request.RawUrl I am not getting the domain name (at least in development).

For example, if my url locally is:

http://localhost:2343/some/thing

The call to Request.RawUrl is giving me back:

/some/thing

I recall it returns everything, is this the behaviour b/c it is local dev?

**Update**

I am also using Url Re-Writing so things like Request.Url.AbsoluteUri return back the internal url, not the re-written url that i need to get.

is javascript the only way then?

Or I maybe I can use Request.RawUrl for the url part, and then just get the domain name part somehow?  (sometimes it has a port too...)

Answer (score 7):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx):

> The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain information. In the URL string http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx, the raw URL is /articles/recent.aspx. The raw URL includes the query string, if present.

You can use [`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) to get the entire thing.

Comment: Problem is I am using url re-writting, so maybe the only way is to get the url via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

See what you get with `Request.Url.`

Answer (score 1):

The `RawUrl` returns just that, the URL after your domain.

[See this page for an example of RawURL](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/httprequestclassrawurl.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN document on [Request.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx):

`The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain information.`

You are looking for [Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is by design. [`RawUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl%28VS.71%29.aspx) only returns the part of the url following the domain name, plus any querystring parameters.

If you want the full url, use [`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To make this work for rewritten URL's you can combine the following:

```
var result = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.RawUrl;
```